# Avoid error "Element type is invalid" with React.createElement in HOC React

Tags: reactjs, router, higher-order-components

I want to implement the `PrivateRoute` HOC which will check if the user is logged in then render the corresponding component, otherwise redirect to the login page.

**Here is the PrivateRoute HOC:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        sessionStorage.getItem('userToken') ? (
            React.createElement(component, props)
        ) : (
                <Redirect to={{
                    pathname: '/login',
                }} />
            )
    )} />
);

export default PrivateRoute;
```

**Here's how I'm using it:**

```
import PrivateRoute from './components/HOC/PrivateRoute';

...

render() {
    if (this.props.hasError) return <h1>Sorry, something went wrong...</h1>;

    if (this.props.isLoading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={<Home /> } />
          <Route exact path="/login" render={props => <Login {...props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/registration" render={props => <Registration {...props} />} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/account" component={<Account />} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**But it throws an error:**
[image]

I find a [GitHub thread](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13445) where I find a possible answer for why it happens like that, but I don't know how to implement that answer for my case:

I tried some experimental ways to achieve that but everything fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) accepts a type or a React component **before it invoked**.

```
React.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

> The `type` argument can be either a tag name string (such as 'div' or 'span'), a **React component type** (a class or a function), or a **React fragment type**.

---

```
const Component = () => <>Hello</>;

// Good
React.createElement(Component)
React.createElement("div")

// Bad
React.createElement(<div/>)
```

In your case you use the "bad" version.

You should use `cloneElement` or fix it with a wrapper:

```
// Good
React.cloneElement(<Component />)

// Or make a wrapper
React.createElement(() => <Component />));
```

So finally:

```
// Change to clone
React.cloneElement(component, props)

// **OR** make a wrapper
<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={() => <Home />} />
```

Comment: Both ways are working great. Thank you for a proper explanation!